# The type telerik:RadVirtualGrid was not found

Tags: wpf

Error   XLS0414 The type 'telerik:RadVirtualGrid' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

```
 xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
also using this reference and this code
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MyViewModel}">
            <telerik:RadVirtualGrid DataProvider="{Binding DataProvider}"  
                            Margin="5" >
            </telerik:RadVirtualGrid>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.